# GMAP.NET - from code-behind to MVVM + markers

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, mvvm, gmap.net

I'm playing with this library because it seems quite useful for app developing that involves locations.

**Q1:** I was able to implement this in code-behind but I'm not able to transfer this to MVVM architecture. How can I do it?

**Q2:** if you see my code you can notice that I'm trying to use markers but for some reason I am only able to use marker.Shape (rectangle, ellipse, wtv). I want to use the standard ones from the GoogleMaps. Gmarkergoogle doesn't seems to exists anymore in GMap API. How can I do it? There is some other library to use? Need a little help over here as well.

**OverviewView CODE**

```
 public partial class OverviewView : UserControl
{
    public OverviewView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Initialize map:
        myMap.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly; // get tiles from server only

        PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(42.742826, -77.030212);
        PointLatLng point1 = new PointLatLng(41.742826, -77.030212);
        //Not use proxy
        //Center map on a point
        //GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(point);
        var marker = new GMapMarker(point);
        var marker1 = new GMapMarker(point1);

        marker.Shape = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 1,
            Height = 100,
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5
        };
        marker1.Shape = new Rectangle
        { 
            Width = 1,
            Height = 100,
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5
        };
        myMap.Markers.Add(marker);
        myMap.Markers.Add(marker1);
        myMap.ZoomAndCenterMarkers(5);
        myMap.Position = point;
        /*   GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
       GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528),
        GMarkerGoogleType.green);
       markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
       gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);*/


    }
}
```

Best regards and thanks in advance for the time,
Antoine

Comment: "Need a little help over here as well" is not a question. Actually there is no question at all in this post.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've already edited the questions. I thought that what I was asking was clear through my text, but you are right and now is clearer :)

Comment: @Antoine, have you managed to use this control in MVVM?